# Nvidia not working on ubuntu 16.04, GeForce 940MX

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, cuda

The nvidia driver and cuda were working fine until 1 month back. Either due to some update or tool installation, it is not working anymore.

Platform:

```
Laptop: Thinkpad T450p
GPU: GeForce 940MX
Nvidia Driver: Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.111 from nvidia-384 (proprietary)
Ubuntu: 16.04
Secure Boot: disabled (while booting, it shows at top of screen: booting in insecure mood)
Dual Boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04a
```

Issues:

```
nvidia-smi:
nvidia-smi: command not found

nvidia-settings:
ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
** Message: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? yes
ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application profiles will continue to work, but
       values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible
       values and descriptions.
```

I select nvidia with prime-select

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
    Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', 'mesa']
    Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', 'mesa-egl']
    Info: selecting nvidia-384 for the nvidia profile
    update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-384/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
    update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-384/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in manual mode
    update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-384/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
    update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-384/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in manual mode
```

If I do nvidia-smi now:

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Checking display devices:

```
sudo lshw -short | grep -i --color display
/0/100/1.2/0              display        GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
/0/100/2                  display        Intel Corporation
```

Grub settings original:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Modified and still no change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Windows acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Check bios:

```
inxi -F && dmesg | grep -i error
... (everything normal output) ...
[    0.237412] ACPI Error: [_PPC] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20150930/dswload-378)
[    0.237435] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_PR.CPU0.GCAP] (Node ffff880430a267d0), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20150930/psparse-542)
[    0.237445] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_PR.CPU0._OSC] (Node ffff880430a26758), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20150930/psparse-542)
[    0.237449] ACPI: Marking method _OSC as Serialized because of AE_ALREADY_EXISTS error
[    2.952395] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    3.117387] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.118631] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.118650] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.042936] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[    5.042960] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

I have no idea what ruined it, but nvidia-smi is not working anymore.
I tried

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

and chose from additional drivers from ubuntu. Still no solution.

I tried installing `nvidia-390.25` downloaded from their website. At the end of installation, I get `failed to load drm-module` error. And after rebooting, I still get the same problems.

What else can I try? (I am in no situation to install format the whole ubuntu partiion and install from scratch as I have tonnes of programs/libraries/files what I cannot loose or reinstall)